# IDL for JSON REST/RPC interface

Tags: json, rest, rpc, protocol-buffers, idl

We are designing a fairly complex REST API, in which most of the I/O are JSON encoded objects with a specific structure. One challenge we have found is to document the API in such a way that makes it easier for clients to post correct input and process output. Because the data of both the input and output requires fairly complex JSON objects, client developers often introduce bugs related to the structure of the I/O objects.

With all of the JSON web API's these days, I would have hoped for a general solution, but I am having a hard time finding one. I looked into [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/) which is a json-validation schema but both the IETF draft and implementations seem to be fairly immature (even though they have been around for a while, which is not a good sign).

A slightly different approach is offered by [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/), where the schema is not used for validation, but actually  required for the encoding/decoding of the message. Of these 2, Avro seems to have rather limited documentation and implementations. ProtoBuf seems better, but I am not sure if this is really suitable to use in the browser to call a JSON api?

Now I am starting to doubt if I am looking at this from the right angle. Are there other methods available to make my API a bit more strong-typed'ish? Or is a formal description of a JSON REST/RPC API something that defeats the purpose of using JSON?

Edit: 6 months after this topic we found [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), which is very close to what we were lookin for.

Comment: If you really need to use an existing solution, I would just go with json-schema, which seems easy enough to use. Otherwise, I don't think it's too difficult to check the JSON structure yourself - check that each objects have the properties you need, and do that recursively if you have too. Unlike XML, JSON is pretty simple to validate, which might be why no proper schema validation solution exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below a reply I received by email from Douglas Crockford.

> I am not a believer in schemas as an alternative to input validation.
>   There are properties that cannot be verified from the syntax. I think
>   that was one of the ways that XML went wrong.
>
> If your formats are too complex, then I would look at simplifying
>   them.

Answer (score 4):

Such systems exist and I'm the author of one of them. It is called [Piqi-RPC](http://piqi.org/doc/piqi-rpc/) and it does IDL-based validation of the input and output parameters for RPC-style APIs over HTTP.

It supports JSON, XML and Google Protocol Buffers as data representation formats for input and output of HTTP POST requests. Clients can choose to use any of the three formats and specify their choice using the standard `Accept` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers.

So, yes, in theory, you are looking in the right direction. However, at the moment, Piqi-RPC supports writing servers only in Erlang and it wouldn't be very useful for you if you use a different stack. I heard that Apache Thrift also supports JSON over HTTP transport, but I haven't checked. Another kind of similar system I know of (also for Erlang) is called [UBF](http://norton.github.com/ubf/). I have heard of libraries for Java that can parse and validate JSON based on Protocol Buffers specification (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/).

The idea itself is far from being new, but there aren't many systems that approach it in practice. It is a challenging problem.

Historically, IDLs were used for interface definition and binary data serialization and not so much for validating dynamic data interchange formats (e.g. XML and JSON) which emerged later. Sun-RPC IDL and CORBA IDL fall in the first category. WSDL would be one of few examples covering both areas, but it is a terrible piece of technology and it would be a bad choice for most modern systems. In addition, there are many schema languages (also known as DDLs -- data definition languages), most of which are highly specialized and work with only one representation format, e.g. XML or JSON schemas. Few of those have stable implementations.

The [Piqi project](http://piqi.org) and Piqi-RPC, which is based on it, are build around several fairly simple realizations:

- DLL doesn't have to be explicitly tied to any particular data representation format or built around it. Instead, such language can be fairly universal and cover wide range of practical use-cases (e.g. cross-language data serialization and data validation) and data formats (e.g. JSON, XML, Protocol Buffers).
- IDL for RPC-style communication can be implemented as a thin, mostly syntactic layer on top of the universal DDL.
- Such IDL and interface specifications can be transport agnostic.

Speaking of REST-style APIs over HTTP compared to RPC-style APIs over HTTP.

With RPC-style APIs, service developer or an automated system have to validate three things: function name (according to some service naming scheme), input and, if you choose so, output.

In case of REST-style APIs, people get themselves in trouble for no good reason. Now, they have a *lot more* stuff to validate: arbitrarily complex URL syntax, including dynamic parameters encoded in URL segments (for all HTTP methods) and URL query string (only for HTTP GET method), HTTP method correspondence (whether it should be GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.), HTTP body when some parameters go there (sometimes they do it manually twice for parameters represented in JSON and XML), custom HTTP headers, and separately -- service documentation. Imagine an IDL supporting all that!

Answer (score 2):

XML is better for RESTful services in many ways. It has native linking (`<link href=`, for all those [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) fans), native language support (`lang="en"`) and a great ecosystem.

It is also better for future proofing and future API refactorings. Converting this:

```
<profile>
    <username>alganet</username>
</profile>
```

To support more usernames:

```
<profile>
    <username>alganet</username>
    <username>alexandre</username>
</profile>
```

Is much more simpler to do **without breaking existing clients** using XML. JSON is hard on that.

If you really need JSON, JSON-Schema is the way to go. It's immature, but I don't know anything better on that case. Maybe your consumers could choose between XML and JSON, so they can choose between a small payload (JSON) or RESTful candies (XML) using Content Negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the answer to your last question is yes. If you need a way to constrain and document the JSON "schema", why didn't you go with XML in the first place? It is not that much harder to parse, and being able to enforce a schema for it is a great advantage.